# Delphi compile-time integer conversion warnings?

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, compiler-warnings, delphi-xe

In Delphi XE or 2006, is there any way to detect **at compile time** that implicit conversions between integer types may lose data? I realize it's possible to detect this with runtime checking. I would want it to flag the following example **even if the "big" value were 1.** (We're considering changing int to bigint for certain database keys and want to determine the impact on a large legacy codebase.)

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  small: Integer;
  big: Int64;
begin
  big := 3000000000000;
  small := big;  // Detect me!

  Writeln(small);
end.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You won't get any warnings or hints at compile time. The Delphi compiler does **not** do any program flow analysis which tells it that `big` contains a too large value when it is assigned to `small`. It silently truncates the value to make it fit in the smaller type. I tried with `Shortint`, a signed byte-sized type and even that did not give a warning or hint.

And there is no way to make Delphi warn you. It would be nice. Perhaps you can suggest it in [QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com) (if it wasn't already suggested)?

Comment: No need for new features since range checking catches all such defects

Comment: It catches it at _runtime_. It would be nice to get a _compile time_ hint or warning about loss of precision or truncation of values.

Comment: compiler can't know until run time what a variable contains

Comment: @David - agree, but for this type of a simple variable assignment might be more predictable and warn about it

Comment: @daemon would be a lot of effort to add such a feature for trivial return. Time better spent writing 64 bit compiler and fixing all the defects in the product.

Comment: @David: the compiler can warn that you are assigning an 8 byte type like Int64 to a 1 byte type like Shortint and that this may result in a loss of precision or truncation. Note that the compiler does something similar for conversion between AnsiString and UnicodeString, even if the UnicodeString only contains code points in the ASCII range.

Comment: @David: in what way would it be a lot of effort? It just adds some diagnostics, and the compiler must already be aware of the conversion between different types and add code to truncate anyway. It just requires a little more verbosity.

Comment: OP is asking for warnings at compile time based on value of variables

Comment: He is asking about implicit conversion between integer types, and that that may lose data. He wants warnings about this possible loss of data. He is not interested in values; he even says `I would want it to flag the following example even if the "big" value were 1.` So the value is not important.

Comment: @David - Rudy's correct. The value is not important; the implicit conversion is. Sorry about the ambiguity.

Comment: I'm of two minds about this: One one hand, I see the value of such a thing. On the other, the number of warnings that would be raised may very likely be *massive*. For those of us who like their compilations to be warning free, it'd generate a lot of noise and be a lot of work to track down and refactor or explicitly cast every warned expression.

Comment: @afrazier: I'm not so sure there would be that many warnings. People do no tend to mix types that often. They tend to use the type that is declared for the variable that is assigned to it.  -- And it could be someting that is switched on or off. <g>

Comment: If the value doesn't matter then both question and answer need to be edited

Comment: The very large value was merely to demonstrate that there is loss of information when you assign "big" to "small". The question is clearly about compile-time integer conversion warnings.

Comment: @rudy where does program flow analysis come into it then?

Comment: Because the compiler could have seen (just as we do), that the value wouldn't fit. More or less as if the code had been: `small := 30000000000;`. The compiler doesn't do that either.

Comment: @rudy make your mind up. Is it about data type size, or the values in the variables at run time? One minute you argue one way, the next the other way. It's not a sign of weakness to improve your answers.

Comment: @David - Rudy correctly answered my question to my satisfaction. I have edited the question to emphasize that this is about compile-time types, not run-time values.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis take a look into `Pascal Analyzer`

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi, even in Delphi 10.3 -- no.
But take a look into software calling 'Pascal Analyzer', mfg by [www.peganza.com](http://www.peganza.com)

They have a lot of options and one of them is (taken from software Help):

[image]

Source code for test, take a look into line #32:

[image]

Analyze result show possible bad assignment in line #32:

[image]